# Translate point coordinates to image

Tags: java, math, language-agnostic, coordinates

How to translate Cartesian point coordinates to BufferedImage pixels from the top left corner?
The question is in the context of plotting 2D math functions.

Let the image of height `h` and width `w` be limited by (ymin,ymax) and (xmin,xmax).

So far I've managed to properly translate X coordinates, but I have no idea what to do with the second dimension.

```
private int transformX(double x)
{          
    return (int)((double)w*(x-xmin)/(xmax-xmin));
}

private int transformY(double x)
{          
    ?
}
```

**@UPDATE**

It's not a homework. TransformY is much more complex because Y axis is reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private int transformY(double y)
      {        
          return (int)((double)h*(-y+ymax)/(ymax-ymin));
      }
```